# Is it possible to achieve Load balancing by only using Ribbon without any Service Registry?

Tags: java, spring

I am using two services namely ProducerService and ConsumerService,
and running ProducerService as ApplicationService on three ports and trying to consume ConsumerService as a client from client-side.

Is it possible to load balance without using any service registry like(eureka, consul) ??

Here, I attached the code which I have tried..

```java
****ConsumerService****

======Consumer Controller======

@RestController
@RibbonClient(name="ProducerService",configuration=RibbonConfig.class)
public class ConsumerController {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello()
    {
        String url="http://ProducerService/value";
        return restTemplate.getForObject(url,String.class);
    }
}

======Consumer Application======

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumerService2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumerService2Application.class, args);
    }
}

======Ribbon Configuration File======

import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl;

public class RibbonConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    IClientConfig clientConfig;
    
    @Bean
    public IPing ping(IClientConfig clientConfig)
    {
        return new PingUrl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }
}

======Configuration File======

import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
public class config {   
    
    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
    
  
}

======Consumer Yaml File======

server:
  port: 8080
ProducerService:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8081,localhost:8082,localhost:8083
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 15000
    
    
    
****ProducerService****

======Producer Controller======
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    @GetMapping("/value")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello application running on port: " + port;
    }
}

======ProducerApplication======
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProducerServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProducerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}

======Producer properties File======

server.port=8083
spring.application.name=ProducerService
```

Comment: Can you share code what you have tried till now for achieve this scenario.

Comment: Yeah Abhishek, I shared the code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You need to add update the `application.yml` as

```
ProducerService:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8000,localhost:8001 #depends upon your server
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 2000
```

in restTemplate give the service name alone properly.

Answer (score 0):

yes , follow this step's: 
in client service

add `spring-cloud-starter-ribbon`  dependency to your pom.xml file 
then in `application.properies` file add :

```
ribbon.eureka.enables = false 
ProducerService.listOfServers = http://localhost:8081,http://localhost:8082,..
```

now rest client knows ProducerService instances location

finally in your controller class you should add @RibbonClient then you can call and loadbalance by calling ProducerService instead of ip address :

```
@RibbonClient(name = "ProducerService")
@Controller
public class Controller{
    ...
}
```